# ConTeXt minimal example with twocolumn, Footnotes, quote, lists, headings

Tags: context, two-column, examples, grid-typesetting

I am thinking about moving at least for some purposes to ConTeXt because of the grid typesetting option. However I did not find a minimal working example that shows how to use Footnotes, Lists, the quote-environment, Headings etc. (the very basic elements that one needs in a lot of texts). How would one accomplish something like the following?

```
\documentclass[DIV=21,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\pdfprotrudechars=2
\pdfadjustspacing=2
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\title{Some Title Lipsum}
\author{Cicero}
\date{December 21 2016 }
\begin{document}
\maketitle


\lipsum[1-2] \begin{quote}
    Some Text in a quote environment        
\end{quote}
\section{One Section}\footnote{Some Footnote Some FootnoteSome FootnoteSome FootnoteSome FootnoteSome FootnoteSome FootnoteSome FootnoteSome Footnote }
\lipsum[1-4]
\subsection{A Subsection}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Some List \item Next Item \begin{enumerate}
    \item Next Level \item Next Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
 \section{A Header}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Some Text}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Aditya’s answer, here a full example, kind of resembling what you posted in LaTeX.

```
\mainlanguage[en]

\definefontfeature
  [default][default]
  [
    protrusion=quality,
    expansion=quality,
    onum=yes,
  ]

\setupbodyfont[pagella]

\setupalign[hz,hanging,tolerant]

\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\definenarrower
  [quote]
  [left=25pt,
   right=25pt]

\defineheadalternative
  [centered]
  [alternative=vertical,
   renderingsetup=headrenderings:centered]

\startsetups headrenderings:centered
    \vbox {
        \headsetupspacing
        \veryraggedcenter
        \ifconditional\headshownumber
            \headnumbercontent
            \kern\headnumberdistance
        \fi
        \begstrut
        \headtextcontent
        \endstrut
    }
\stopsetups

\setuphead[alternative=centered]

\starttexdefinition unexpanded placetitle
  \ifgridsnapping\startlinecorrection\fi
    \blank[2em,force]
    \startalignment[center]
      {\tfb\documentvariable{metadata:title}\par}
      \blank[1.5em]
      {\tfa\documentvariable{metadata:author}\par}
      \blank[1em]
      {\tfa\documentvariable{metadata:date}\par}
    \stopalignment
    \blank[1.5em,force]
  \ifgridsnapping\stoplinecorrection\fi
\stoptexdefinition

\startdocument
  [
    metadata:title={Some Title Lipsum},
    metadata:author={Cicero},
    metadata:date={December 21, 2016},
  ]

\placetitle

\startmixedcolumns[balance=yes]

  \input knuth

  \startquote
    Some Text in a quote environment
  \stopquote

  \startsection[title={One Section}]

    \input knuth\footnote{Some Footnote}

    \startsubsection[title={A Subsection}]

      \startitemize[n]
      \item Some List
      \item Next Item
        \startitemize[a]
        \item Next Level
        \item Next Item
        \stopitemize
      \stopitemize

    \stopsubsection

  \stopsection

  \startsection[title={A Header}]

    \input knuth

    \startsubsection[title={A Subsection}]

      \input knuth

    \stopsubsection

  \stopsection

\stopmixedcolumns

\stopdocument
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just changed the pagenumbering and the page layout a bit. One thing: how would one center the section, subsection and chapter?

Comment: @PeterStrawson Does `\setuphead[alternative=middle]` suit your needs?

Comment: I thought so, too. But the problem is that it puts the numbers in a line above the header – I want to have it before the text of the header.

Comment: @PeterStrawson See updated answer with centered titles.  (I had to do it by hand, even though `\setuphead[alternative=text,align=middle]` should have intuitively worked)

Answer (score 4):

## Two columns

There are various two-column mechanisms in ConTeXt. The one that is closest to LaTeX's two-column mechanism is `mixedcolumns`. (Note that the default `columns` mechanism does not support multi-column footnotes). So, a basic example is:

```
\starttext
\startmixedcolumns[balance=yes]
 \dorecurse{10}{\input knuth\footnote{A quote from Knuth.}}
\stopmixedcolumns
\stoptext
```

## Lists

In ConTeXt, `itemize` environment is used for both the `itemize` and `enumerate` environments of LaTeX. The basic example (with columns) is:

```
\setupitemize[2][packed][stopper=)]
\starttext
\startmixedcolumns
  \startitemize[n]
    \item Some List
    \item Next Item
      \startitemize[a]
        \item Next Level
        \item Next Item
      \stopitemize
  \stopitemize
\stopmixedcolumns
\stoptext
```

## Quote

The closest equivalent to `quote` environment in ConTeXt is `narrower`.

```
\setupitemize[2][packed][stopper=)]
\starttext
\startmixedcolumns
  \input knuth
  \startnarrower
    Some text in narrower environment
  \stopnarrower
  \input knuth
\stopmixedcolumns
\stoptext
```

## Headings, etc.

Although `\section{...}`, `\subsection{...}`, etc. work in ConTeXt, the recommended usage is `\startsection[title={....}] .... \stopsection` environments.

Comment: Please mention that unnumbered sections have different names instead of a star.  You could also show how to make a new quote environment using `\definestartstop`.  Nevertheless +1